# Pulling MasterPage from right side in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'd like to ask whether or not it is possible to make master page to appear from right side (opposite of it's default behaviour) in xamarin.forms (and preferably with XAML) and if it's possible,would you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it is not possible. 
You can try [Right Master Detail Page](http://www.xam-consulting.com/slideoverkit-xamarin-forms/)

```
public RightSideMasterPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();
    // You must set IsFullScreen in this case, 
    // otherwise you need to set HeightRequest, 
    // just like the QuickInnerMenu sample
    this.IsFullScreen = true;
    // You must set WidthRequest in this case
    this.WidthRequest = 250;
    this.MenuOrientations = MenuOrientation.RightToLeft;

    // You must set BackgroundColor, 
    // and you cannot put another layout with background color cover the whole View
    // otherwise, it cannot be dragged on Android
    this.BackgroundColor = Color.White;

    // This is shadow view color, you can set a transparent color
    this.BackgroundViewColor = Color.FromHex ("#CE766C");
}
```

Comment: That was correct back 7 years ago but now the link seems broken

Comment: I found that project on GitHub: https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit